# symfony2 image unable to find file

Tags: php, symfony

I have following code in base.html.twig:

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/images/logo.png' %}
<img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Logo" />
{% endimage %}
```

And this file exists in this folder but symfony write this one:

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Unable to find file "@AppBundle/Resources/images/logo.png".") in "base.html.twig".

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

For Assetic you can use the %kernel.root_dir% parameter. In your code that would be:

```
{% image '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/images/logo.png' %}
<img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Logo" />
{% endimage %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put your image under web/images directory and use this code:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" />
```

Or you can maintain it where it is and use this code after calling assets:install command:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/logo.png') }}" />
```

Comment: He is trying to use assetic

Comment: Exacly! i try to use assetic :). How can i do that?